# Не отрабатывается нажатие кнопки в апплете. В чем может быть дело

Tags: applet, java, swing

В продолжение темы "Как поместить диалоговое окно в Java апплет?".

Проблему с выводом апплета удалось преодолеть. Но возникла новая: при открытии апплета в браузере (пробовал на IE 8, Mozilla 3.6) при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, хотя в Applet Viewer все отрабатывается нормально без ошибок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я на этот раз накосячил?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

public class Test extends JApplet {

    public void start() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Выбранный файл");
        label.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(label);

        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 10)));

        JButton button = new JButton("Выбрать файл");
        button.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    String fullname = file.getPath();
                                        label.setText(fullname);
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }
}
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Возможно обозреватель блокирует. Если у тебя там какие-то плагины стоят, попробуй 3й браузер =) Только что проверил - работает, но дольше чем я ожидал =)

Comment: Проверил в Opera 9, Chrome, расшарил все возможные настройки обозревателя - результат нулевой. Думаю проблема в объектах апплета, которые отображаются в Applet Viewer, но блокируются или не работают в web обозревателях. Знать бы в каких именно объектах)).
Gorets, если не трудно, подскажи в каком браузере открывал и до конца ли отработался сценарий?  Там по идее при нажатии на кнопку открывается JFileChooser и после выбора файла меняется надпись на label. И ещё раз спасибо за внимание к моей проблеме).

Comment: да, отрабатывает, надпись меняется - на полный путь файла, кинь еще код штмл странички

Comment: Проблема благополучно разрешилась подписыванием .jar файла с апплетом. Все работает. Gorets, deivan, огромное спасибо за участие и помощь. Нужна будет помощь от меня (web, php, SQL) - буду рад помочь - icq в профиле)).

Answer (score 1):

Этот код не будет работать, поскольку апплет изначально, по своей сути, не должен видеть пользовательских файлов, он как бы в своей виртуальной машине работает.

Comment: Но вне браузера он их видит и работает. Хотя класс один и тот же. Более того он может видеть пользовательские файлы и работать с ними если пользователь дал свое согласие на то, например, посредством диалогового окна. Иначе не существовало бы реализованных на java форм отправки файлов на сервер и т.п. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Формы отправки данных на сервер (на сайтах) используют джаваскрипт, жквери, аякс -- но не апплет.

Comment: Есть и на java, видел пару раз. Тогда ещё один пример: апплеты для ЭЦП на правительственных сайтах - через апплет получают путь к файлу на клиентской машине и подписывают их. Так что не так все просто.

Comment: Действительно, я порылся в манускриптах - возможность есть, если апплет "подписать". Но что это за процесс и насколько он трудоемок - мне неведомо.

Comment: Вот и я про то)). Пытливая и творческая мысль начальства заставляет нас делать невозможное - возможным, доказывая верность утверждения, что в жизни всегда есть место подвигу). Будем рыть дальше.